# Illegal character in query at index

Tags: android

I am using `HTTPGET` request to get data from server. when i am passing the url ir giving me the error of

```
04-29 11:30:56.514: V/Exception(7745): Illegal character in query at index 129
```

but i am hitting the url on browser it is giving me the proper response

i am using following code for `HTTPGET`

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
        return processRequest(is).toString();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        Log.v("Exception", exception.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Post query string to find out that illegal character at index 129

Comment: 04-29 11:30:56.514: V/Exception(7745): Illegal character in query at index 129: http://192.168.1.43/Enc/examples/decrypt.php?Message=AwFKoyJNUOZsQstewZEdphE3zDJorNzeaBmfk7+lqtgpxQxah7liCR+jMxw5L5tREcd+cKiGKMgq
04-29 11:30:56.514: V/Exception(7745): rwrQMYYRv88Y9WZUleXQjgKA8NBuq5DkaA

Answer (score 4):

You need to encode your URL

like this,

```
try {

    String simpleUrl = "http://www.abc.com/?email=abc&pass=efg";
    String encodedurl = URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now pass `encodedurl` String to   `new HttpGet(encodedurl);`.

Comment: 04-29 11:45:02.421: V/Exception(9040): Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=http://192.168.1.43/Enc/examples/decrypt.php?Message=AwHQUDn/qeTUYhSP1BAzCtfU41VKtTev82lLNmwbp5bwPMXYnlr0hmxLJwUc8wDY0bxiq/Lp6XPV

Comment: paste your url string ?

Comment: 04-29 11:47:41.069: V/encodedeo url(9369): http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.43%2FEnc%2Fexamples%2Fdecrypt.php%3FMessage%3DAwFpwwEX9xxntmFga8UFgsQPR3ajFQWYMSY%2BQT2wbs8Ft6NtmyTn91rIOwKCGmAr6rWNz370tn4L%0Ac%2FvDmtL1%2FyDpDg96ysnPKUh0jUP49r%2BKKA%0A

Comment: 04-29 11:47:40.999: V/value cipher text(9369): http://192.168.1.43/Enc/examples/decrypt.php?Message=AwFpwwEX9xxntmFga8UFgsQPR3ajFQWYMSY+QT2wbs8Ft6NtmyTn91rIOwKCGmAr6rWNz370tn4L

Comment: please add `http://` or `https://` at beginning. Note this url doesn't exist on network please used valid path. it giving 404 error means url not exist.

Comment: i am working on local network...it cant be accessible outside..and the encoded url is having http at the beginnng...the how can i add one more

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51644/discussion-between-lavekush-agrawal-and-asiya)

Comment: you need to add in simpleURl .

Answer (score 1):

```
String link="http://example.php?string1="+URLEncoder.encode(string1)+"&string2="+URLEncoder
.encode(string2)+"&string3="+URLEncoder.encode(string3)+"&string4="+URLEncoder.encode(string4)+"";
```